# Make phone sleep after a call is made with intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Is it possible to make screen go to sleep after a call is made from a background app?
currently my app makes an emergency call using `intent.ACTION_CALL` even when phone is sleeping and it wakes it up to the dialer.
i want to make it go back to sleep right after the call started.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far

Comment: this is an info question not a coding problem, i need to know if what i want to do is possible and in which way

Answer (score 1):

Make below permission in Menifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Use below code to make phone screen go off -

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
//if you want to make phone go to sleep mode then use 
    wakelock.acquire();
//if you want to make phone go off from sleep mode then use 
    wakelock.release();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but, this is when you want to wake the phone, i am trying to make it sleep.

Comment: yes, but this just makes the phone go to sleep by the settings configured in the phone, not when i am releasing the wakelock